# lighting problems after gldisable(gl_cull_face) in opengl es 2.0

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I have been working in a skull with opengl es 2.0. The skull appeared without some faces:

[image]

After that I dedided to disable gl_cull_face. The problem with the faces was

solved  but the  the skull appears now without light and I haven´t changed shader code:

[image]

I have tried with other lighting algorithms and the skull continues black. I can't understand what is the relationship between gldisable(gl_cull_face) and lighting. The shader code is this:

Vertex Shader:

```
uniform mediump mat4 MODELVIEWMATRIX;
uniform mediump mat4 PROJECTIONMATRIX;
uniform mediump mat3 NORMALMATRIX;
uniform mediump vec3 LIGHTPOSITION;

varying lowp vec3 lightcolor;
attribute mediump vec3 POSITION;
attribute lowp vec3 NORMAL;
lowp vec3 normal;
attribute mediump vec2 TEXCOORD0;
varying mediump vec2 texcoord0;

void main( void ) {

   mediump vec3 position =  vec3( MODELVIEWMATRIX * vec4( POSITION, 1.0 ) );
   normal = normalize( NORMALMATRIX * NORMAL );
   mediump vec3 lightdirection = normalize( LIGHTPOSITION - position );
   lowp float ndotl = max( dot( normal, lightdirection ), 0.0 );
   lightcolor = ndotl * vec3( 1.0 );
   gl_Position = PROJECTIONMATRIX * vec4( position, 1.0 );
   texcoord0 = TEXCOORD0;
  }
```

Fragment Shader:

```
 varying mediump vec2 texcoord0;
 uniform sampler2D DIFFUSE;
 varying lowp vec3 lightcolor;

 void main( void ) {
   gl_FragColor = texture2D( DIFFUSE, texcoord0 ) * vec4( lightcolor, 1.0 ) + vec4( 0.1);
 }
```

Thank you.

Comment: Are you using the depth buffer? I wonder if the backside faces (which were previously culled) could be getting drawn over the front faces. It would make sense for the back faces to be dark because their normal points away from the light.

Comment: Yes, I am using the depth buffer like the example 4.1 of this link [link](http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9780596804824/chrealism.html)

Comment: I have discovered that when I put  glDepthFunc( GL_ALWAYS) after glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST) the skull appears well lighted but with some black squares[link] (http://img805.imageshack.us/img805/1230/glalways.jpg)